# Decision Tree taking too long to execute

Tags: decision-trees, cross-validation, databases

I am training a Decision Tree Regressor on a relatively small data. The dimensions of my train and test sets are (34164, 10) and (8514, 10). Here is the relevant code:

```
y = np.log(data2['price'])
data2.drop(['price'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

num_cols = [cname for cname in data2.columns if data2[cname].dtype in ['int64', 'float64']]
cat_cols = [cname for cname in data2.columns if data2[cname].dtype == 'object']

num_trans = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')
cat_trans = Pipeline(steps = [('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')), 
                          ('onehotencode', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'))])

preproc = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('cat', cat_trans, cat_cols), 
                                        ('num', num_trans, num_cols)])


dtr_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 69, criterion = 'mae')

dtr_pipe = Pipeline(steps = [('preproc', preproc), ('model', dtr_model)])

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data2, y, test_size = 0.2, 
random_state=69)


# BASELINE MODEL
cross_dtr_score = -1 * cross_val_score(dtr_pipe, train_x, train_y, cv = 5,
                                    n_jobs = -1, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error')
base_dtr_score = cross_dtr_score.mean()
```

The problem is it is taking too long to run, even for the baseline model. This is the first time I am facing this problem as usually any kind of tree based model does not take this long. Also the train and test dataset is not huge. So why is it taking such a long time to run even for something as simple as a baseline model? By such a long time I mean more than 15 minutes!

Comment: Apparently you have some categorical features. How many dimensions after one-hot encoding? I would suspect that there are too many, in this case you should simplify your categorical variables probably.

Comment: @Erwan after OHE I get 306 features. And I cannot further simply the features without loosing valuable info. I guess the problem has something to do with Pipelines. I think they are making the computation slow but I'm not sure.

Comment: Then that's not the reason, it's a very reasonable number. I don't have any other idea, except that I'd be curious to know if the processing time is spent more in the preprocessing or the actual training. But I don't know if this is possible to check.

Comment: @Erwan would distributed computing help in this case?

Comment: I don't think so: the only part which can run in parallel is the CV and it's already done. I don't  think the preprocessing can be distributed in sklearn, but I'm not sure. Anyway the first thing would be to identify which part is taking time.

Comment: @Erwan I got why the model was taking such a long time. The metric I chose was MAE which takes considerably longer to calculate than something like MSE. I tried using MSE and it got executed relatively faster. I dont know why this.

Comment: that's really surprising, there's no logical reason for that since MAE is very simple and in general the calculation of the evaluation measure takes very little time compared to the training. The only explanation I can think of would be a bug in the implementation of MAE, but even this seems unlikely.

Comment: Is there any problem if I use MSE instead of MAE? I mean both of them are a measure of error so using one or the other won't matter right?

Comment: No there's no problem with MSE. It gives higher error values than MAE because the error is squared, which means that it penalizes more strongly systems which make larger errors compared to MAE. If you don't have any reason to choose one or the other both are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is facing a similar error, the reason is that `mean_absolute_error` takes more time to calculate. Hence I was facing long execution times. I chose another metric `mean_squared_error` and the execution time decreased drastically. So if the choice of metric is not a restriction, then I'd advise to go for `mean_squared_error` for faster computation times.